# iOS make gesture event programmatically

Tags: uiwebview, sensors

Now...I need your kindly help.
My goal is to make gesture event programmatically.

For example, There is a uiwebview,

In my code:

```
 myWebview.gestureLeft(5);
```

then Webview scroll to left for 5 pixels like when I touch to left for 5 pixels even I didnt touch on webview.

Is it possible?

Now...I am going to implement when I shake phone, webview's content will shake.

But I dont need use call javascript functions.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but I think this is what you're asking.  To do it, I create a gesture recognizer for a specific event.  Next I add the event to the UIWebView.  Finally, create the method that handles the event (doStuff: in this case).

Documentation:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:)];
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer... but...Then...Only I must do touch action on uiwebview...I want to send touch action programmatically